# static_cast on custom class causes copy assignment to fail

Tags: c++

I expected the following program to print "11" but it actually prints "01" so it seems like the first assignment fails.

```
struct A
{
    A(int i = 0) : i_(i) {}
    int i_;
};

int main()
{
    A x(1);
    A y;
    static_cast<A>(y) = x; // *** Fails to assign ***
    std::printf("%i", y.i_);
    y = x;
    std::printf("%i", y.i_);
}
```

If I use a primitive type like`int` instead of `A` then `int x = 1; int y; static_cast<int>(y) = x;` does assign the value `1` to `x`. Is there some way I can get it to work for custom types? I tried adding `operator A() { return *this; }` to `struct A` but that didn't work.

Obviously this is a stupid program but the problem arises in a template function where I have `static_cast<std::remove_const<T>::type>(y) = x` and it was working fine for primitive types but just now failed for a custom type.

Comment: `static_cast<A&>(y)`

Comment: `std::remove_const` should be used with *extreme* care and not lightly - the risk of introducing Undefined Behaviour is great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with any cast, `static_cast<A>(y)` is a temporary copy of `y`. You can cast to a reference type instead (`static_cast<A&>(y)`); more generally, you could achieve this with [`std::add_lvalue_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference).

For the more specific example you described, you'll need `const_cast` rather than `static_cast`, but the basic principle is the same.

Here's [an example that compiles, but has UB](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e47b9e92f412ebd3) because of the modification of a `const` object (and thus returns `0`, not `42`). Without knowing more about what you're trying to do, I shan't attempt to disguise that for the purposes of this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
T foo(T val)
{
    T x{};

    using not_const = typename std::remove_const<T>::type;
    using ref_type  = typename std::add_lvalue_reference<not_const>::type;

    const_cast<ref_type>(x) = val;

    return x;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo<const int>(42) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. But why does it work for primitive types if the value is only being assigned to a temporary copy?

Comment: But `int x = 1; int y = 0; static_cast<int>(y) = x; std::cout << y;` prints `1`

Comment: @GeorgeSkelton: No, it doesn't. It doesn't even compile, at least not in a standard-compliant C++ compiler. Click on the link I just gave you for a live demonstration.

Comment: Ah ok just saw your code. I'm using VS which doesn't give me a warning and appears to "work"